# ASP.Net, incorporating autocomplete

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webforms

This is my first ASP.Net application so please bear with me. I am trying to incorporate auto-complete on a textbox. Currently, I have a WebService set up called ChampNameService.asmx that returns a string from a database depending on what the user types in.

When I test the service, it seems to be working appropriately:

[image: WebService]

[image: WebService2]

The aspx file looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="Webpages/Data/Champdata.aspx">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

        <link href="Styles/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                 $(function () {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax(
                 {
                    url: "ChampNameService.asmx/GetChampionNames",
                    data: "{ 'Champname': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });
            });

        </script>


<p>What champion are you playing? </p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChamps" runat="server"></asp:GridView>


    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
```

This is the part im having issues with:

```
            <link href="Styles/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                 $(function () {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax(
                 {
                    url: "ChampNameService.asmx/GetChampionNames",
                    data: "{ 'Champname': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });
            });

        </script>
```

Im also new to Javascript but I downloaded and imported the correct files and modified the javascript to reflect my own code. What im expecting to happen is that when a user types in a name of a character, it will auto-complete it with the results received from the Webservice. It doesn't seem to be doing this currently. Ive tried numerous methods over a week, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

EDIT: Might the issue be the return value of String in my webservice vs the Json expected in the ajax/javascript?

Comment: What does your browser network trace/script debug window say ? Also: your webservice is actually returning XML, not JSON like your .autocomplete handler is expecting. This won't work. Convert your webservice to an HttpHandler (can return anything, including JSON) or WebAPI controller (returns JSON by default) instead.

Comment: I was thinking that was an issue but I wasn't sure. I ended up using the Ajax Control Toolkit and that worked for me just fine. 

However, I am curious; how do I convert my webservice to an HTTPHandler/WebAPI controller? What are these two things and how do I use them?

I believe an HTTPhandler handles request that come in from the browser?

Comment: Google is your friend. It's pretty easy - [try this guide on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx). The AJAX Control Toolkit / UpdatePanel is simple enough to use but is very inefficient in terms of bandwidth etc. compared to jQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common requirement in web development and there are controls provided by Dev Express to simplify the process. Use the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx). And, [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx)'s an example how to use it.

Comment: It took a while, but after fiddling around with it, I got it to work! Thanks!

Comment: That's great. Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers!